# How can I specify the range of a random number?

Tags: java, range, binary-search-tree

I have binary search tree code that inserts numbers randomly. I can modify size each time, but I want to modify the range of numbers, for example: I want the random number be just one digit or just 2 digits.

How can I do that?

```
public static void main( String[ ] args ) {

    BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree( );
    Random random = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
    int[] randoms = new int[1000];
    Random randGen = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < randoms.length; i++)
    {
        bst.insert( random.nextInt( randoms.length ) );
    }

    System.out.println( "\n sorted :" );

    bst.inorderTraversal( );
    bst.delete (4);

    System.out.println( "\nMax Value:" ); 
    System.out.println(bst.maxValue());
    System.out.println( "\n Min Value:" );
    System.out.println(bst.minValue());

    System.out.println(bst.lookup(1));
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Since you know how to use nextInt, seems like keeping it a certain range should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

- just one digit

  ```
  random.nextInt(10)
  ```
- just 2 digits

  ```
  random.nextInt(90) + 10
  ```

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, Totoo Boo, then please accept it as the answer so that Jakub gets proper credit.