# How can I specify range of numbers?

Tags: java, range, binary-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I specify the range of a random number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639757/how-can-i-specify-the-range-of-a-random-number)

I have this code for binary search tree

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Random random = new Random();


    Tree theTree = new Tree();


    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        numbers.add(i + 1);
    }

    // re-order number, so it seem like random generator
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);

    // inserting into tree
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int no : numbers) {
        theTree.insert(no, 1.5);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Inserting 100 number in tree takes: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds");
    System.out.println("\n\n");
```

I want specify range of random numbers . I want to be just one digit and then just 2 digit then just 4 dijit .

Comment: How has this question not already been answered?

Comment: not same , this diffrent code

Comment: You say you want a one digit, a two digit, then a four digit random number: how is that different?

Comment: diffrent when i calculete efficancy

Comment: Huh? You need to re-write your question so it's actually different, right now it's identical--generating a random number of a certain number of digits, which you've already been shown how to do.

Comment: my code generte number from diffrent digit , I can specify size but can not specify range

Comment: please help me it is necissery to specify digit

Comment: Really? So a two-digit random number isn't in the range of 10-99?

Comment: yes , but my code generte from 1 to 10000 mix betwwen 1 digit , 2 and 3 digits

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I want the code when generte 100 numbers for example I want it all with one digit such as 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3  >>>> etc

Comment: And what's stopping you? You know how to generate a random number with a certain number of digits. Do you know how to loop?

Comment: I agree with Dave; this looks very similar to your other question? You've been told how to generate a random number within a certain range, and you seem to know how to loop given your above code... So what's stopping you combining the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totoo, have you read the JavaDocs for Random yet? The following code shows you how to leverage Random to do this.

```
    Random random = new Random();

    int oneDigit = random.nextInt( 10 );
    int twoDigit = 10 + random.nextInt( 90 );
    int threeDigit = 100 + random.nextInt( 900 );
    int fourDigit = 1000 + random.nextInt( 9000 );

    System.out.println( String.format(
            "oneDigit: %d, twoDigit: %d, threeDigit: %d, fourDigit: %d",
            oneDigit,
            twoDigit,
            threeDigit,
            fourDigit ) );
```

Comment: Also, it is common courtesy to mark answers as correct once someone has answered your question.  Are you doing this?

Comment: ok , I want ask about this theTree.insert(no, 1.5);    1.5 what means ?